# How to select div in place of checkbox?

Tags: html, checkbox

I want to do the functionality of check-box on div , means on click on div the div get selected and i don't want to display the check-box.
How can i do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want like this [Jquery UI Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#default)